# type 'Bool' has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift

i'm new to Swift and following Appcoda book to study IOS programming, here is my code:
-In restaurantDetailViewController class:

```
class RestaurantDetailViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var restaurantImageView:UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var restaurantNameLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var restaurantTypeLabel:UILabel!
@IBOutlet var restaurantLocationLabel:UILabel!

var restaurantImage = ""
var restaurantName = ""
var restaurantType = ""
var restaurantLocation = ""
var isVisited:Bool?

 func tableView(tableView:UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int{
    return 4
}
func tableView(tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cellIndentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!RestaurantDetailViewCell
    switch indexPath.row{
    case 0:
        cell.filedLabel.text = "Name"
        cell.valueLabel.text = restaurantName
    case 1:
        cell.filedLabel.text = "Type"
        cell.valueLabel.text = restaurantType
    case 2:
        cell.filedLabel.text = "Location"
        cell.valueLabel.text = restaurantLocation
    case 3:
        cell.filedLabel.text = "Been here?"
        cell.valueLabel.text = isVisited[indexPath.row] ? "Yes, I have been here" : "No"//I got the error right here

    default:
        cell.filedLabel = nil
        cell.valueLabel = nil

    }
    return cell
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    restaurantImageView.image = UIImage(named: restaurantImage)
    //restaurantNameLabel.text = restaurantName
    //restaurantTypeLabel.text = restaurantType
    //restaurantLocationLabel.text = restaurantLocation
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

I have searched on many topic about my problem however i haven't got any clue, i would very appreciate if you guys could help me. This is the first time i post my question to stackoverflow so if there is anything wrong with my topic and the way i ask the question i hope you guys can remind me gently.
Thanks you very much.

Comment: Just delete `[indexPath.row]` -> `isVisited ? "Yes, I have been here" : "No"`

Comment: I think something seriously wrong with you _model_, because seemingly you just don't have a _model_ at all.

Comment: PS: Declaring `isVisited` as optional is nonsensical. Is there anything else as `yes` or `no`?

Comment: If i don't declare isVisited as optional Xcode will inform me that i got :"class RestaurantDetailViewController has no initializer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iSVisited` is declared as an optional boolean

```
var isVisited:Bool?
```

Updated your `case3` as follows:-

```
cell.valueLabel.text = isVisited ? "Yes, I have been here" : "No"
```

Comment: I did as your instruction but i got the error of : "Optional type '()' cannot be used as boolean, test for '!=nil' instead" .
How can i solve this?

Comment: Oh, i have found the solution by setting false as default value to isVisited and the apps works correctly.